# No Search Provider Icon in Firefox 34

Tags: feature-request

Firefox 34 introduced the [One-Click Searches UI](https://blog.mozilla.org/ux/2014/11/find-it-faster/), where a drop-down box appears below the search bar when typing. This box has icons from search providers, that may be clicked to use that site instead of the default search engine.

Unfortunately, Stack Exchange appears to have no custom Search Provider Icon, so it shows up as the generic grey circle with a magnifying glass.

This was reported on Bugzilla: [Bug 1106043: Search icon doesn't show for some open search providers](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1106043). A programmer just responded with some analysis:

> > I get different behavior for https://stackoverflow.com/ and https://translate.google.com/ in Firefox 33 vs. Firefox 34, though. I think both of them rely on our favicon fallback - https://stackoverflow.com/opensearch.xml and https://translate.google.com/opensearch.xml?hl=en both have relative icon URIs, which I don't think we handle.

He then goes on to identify Firefox code which may have caused the icons to stop being visible.

I'm not a programmer and not aware of how FF handles favicons and Search Provider Icons, but it sounds like the sites whose icons are visible are using a different style of URI than the relative one used by this site.

With Firefox's rapid releases, this could be fixed on their end very soon, but I thought I would bring it up in case updating the way Stack Exchange links to this icon could be beneficial.

Comment: I've edited your tag from [tag:bug] to [tag:feature-request] because I don't see how this is a bug on the Stack Exchange platform. If I'm mistaken, feel free to revert my changes, but please also edit your post to reflect that.

Comment: As I quoted, the Firefox programmer says "I believe both of them rely on our favicon fallback- both have relative icon URIs, which I don't think we handle." This sounds like something can be done about it on this end. I guess it technically isn't a "bug" if you are doing something in a way that Firefox doesn't recognize, but I really just wanted to make staff aware that the site was being represented in a suboptimal way in the most popular browser, and what was being done about it on their end. Not sure what you think I should change about my post.

Comment: And for what it's worth, I've added about a dozen custom search providers to the bar; SE is the only one without an icon.